# Whats the Best way to add a weather overlay to a google map activity?

Tags: android, overlay, weather, weather-api

What i have: I am developing an android application and i have a google map activity that will pull up the users current location.

What i want: To display the local weather of that location using an overlay.

And :what weather API's are best for achieving this, and allowed to be used commercially?

I have browsed around and cant find really any full example code showing how this is done. I find little pieces such as the long & lat get code but thats it. any help or advice would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an Open Source Weather app:
https://github.com/tibnor/OpenAndroidWeather. I hope I could help.